# Sorting Section Headers in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What is a good way of sorting section number strings in Ruby. For example:

```
sections = ["10", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "2", "1", "1.1", "1.1.1", "1.1.2"]
# ["1", "1.1", "1.1.1", "1.1.2", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
```

Comment: How deep do your subsections go? Do you only get "1.2" or is "1.2.6" possible too?

Comment: @mu Sorry, the example didn't include deep nesting, but it is a requirement (i.e. 1.2.6)!

Comment: Aha! It isn't paranoia when they really are you to get you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have to deal with arbitrarily nested subsections then you could do something like this:

```
sections = ["10", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "2", "1", "1.1", "1.2", "1.2.5"]
sections.sort! { |a,b| a.split('.').map(&:to_i) <=> b.split('.').map(&:to_i) }
```

That implementation isn't exactly quick due to the repeated `split` and `map` but you could roll your own [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_Transform) if it was too slow:

```
sections.map  { |e| [e, e.split('.').map(&:to_i) ] } \
        .sort { |a, b| a.last <=> b.last } \
        .map  { |e| e.first }
```

Note that [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001481) does an internal Schwartzian Transform for you:

> The current implementation of sort_by generates an array of tuples containing the original collection element and the mapped value.

So you could also let `sort_by` take care of some of the ugliness:

```
section.sort_by { |e| e.split('.').map(&:to_i) }
```

and get something that is pretty easy to understand at a glance.

Comment: @Wes: You need to compare the individual components as numbers to get "1.2.11" and "10" to come out in the right order.

Comment: @mu I guess I was just thinking that to_f does that for us and make sure I wasn't missing something else.

Comment: @Wes: `to_f` does the trick until you have sub-sub-sections, then you need to split-and-compare-arrays approach because `'11.23.42'.to_f` doesn't quite cut it.

Comment: @mu sorry...slow tonight...you added the extra notation for sub-sections.  In that case then yes but for the original problem to_f is fine.

Comment: If you reverse the order of `[e, e.split('.').map(&:to_i) ]`, you can then just `sort` (no block) and `map(&:last)`

Answer (score 6):

If it is possible that you may go to more than two levels, you can do the following:

```
sections.sort_by{ |section| section.split('.').map(&:to_i)}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Enumerable`'s `sort_by` method:

```
sections.sort_by(&:to_f)
```

Or, the slightly longer version:

```
sections.sort_by{ |section| section.to_f }
```

Answer (score 1):

IF they are always going to be like that you could cast them to floats..

```
sections = ["10", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "2", "1", "1.1", "1.2"]
    => ["10", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "2", "1", "1.1", "1.2"]

sections.sort {|x,y| x.to_f <=> y.to_f}
=> ["1", "1.1", "1.2", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
```